# Conflicting References in ASP.NET Website Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb, .net-standard-2.0, vs-web-site-project

I have built a .NET standard dll that relies on System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager due to the presence of Azure.Cosmos libraries.  When adding the required dlls to my ASP.NET 4.7.2 Website Project I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4382976a\ff659097\assembly\dl3\c46cb292\00cb1086_6aa6d601\System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.DLL'

- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is required by Azure Cosmos libraries
- System.Configuration is required by the ASP.NET Website Project

I have scoured the internet for hours and although I find solutions for Web App Projects, I cannot find anything for legacy Website Projects.  I have tried every suggestion I can find, including modifying web.config settings and csproj settings.

Any help out there would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered converting to a Web Application Project? The Web Site project model is dead.

Comment: That is in our longer term plans, but not possible at the moment.

Comment: Why not? You asked this question 2 hours ago. Converting from a web site project to a web application project can probably be done in less time than that. What's keeping you from doing it?

Comment: There are a number of significant issues preventing us at this time.  I appreciate the input, as moving to a Web App is a valid comment, but I am looking for solutions to how this can be achieved via a Website Project.

Comment: When you say 4.6 do you mean 4.6.1? .netstandard 2.0 isn't supported on 4.6, and the general recommendation is to upgrade to 4.7.2 if you do need to use .netstandard on .net framework. Is that an option?

Comment: We are targeting 4.7.2, sorry it was a mistake in the question that I have updated.  Thanks for pointing that out.